# 9v adapter burned out Leonardo style board

Tags: arduino-leonardo, safety

My first experience with Arduino ended in a tragedy. I bought a Leonardo from ebay and upon arrival, attached it to my laptop. Programmed a simple blink demo with the onboard LED. It started working. Then detached it from USB and plugged in a 9v adapter. The board started smoking and it doesn't work anymore. I measured the voltage of the adapter and it reads 9.7v. So, what is the reason of this tragedy?

***Edit:***

I think that the smoke was from a component close to the processor. Right now, when I attach a 9v battery to the board, both the ON LED and the L LED remains on. The processor also warm.

Comment: I hate to sound like a prick but if you bought a knock-off then it could be absolutely anything.

Comment: Well, it looks like a legitimate made-in-italy one! How can I detect if it is fake or not?

Comment: If you bought it on eBay then it's a knock-off. They are *very*, *very* good at making exact copies. Except where it counts, as you've discovered.

Comment: Did you check the *polarity* of the adapter? If it's reversed the diode (SMT version of a 1N400x) will overheat.

Comment: I checked the polarity of the adapter and it seems OK. When I attach the COM cable of the multimeter to the inner contact of the adapter, it shows +9.7v. Does it confirm that the polarity if OK?

Comment: Common to inner, V to outer? If it reads +9.7 it's the reverse of most adapters.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my previous comment. It reads -9.7v. So, it's correct. And the center pin is marked as positive on the adapter too. So, it looks fine.

Comment: Post a picture. Perhaps seeing what failed will give a clue.

Comment: @Craig: I am not sure if a picture helps or not, since the board looks totally normal. I think that the smoke was from a component close to the processor. Right now, when I attach a 9v battery to the board, both the ON LED and the L LED remains on. The processor also warm.

Comment: While it is possible someone shipped a board with a fake regulator or under-rated or reverse polarity filter cap, I'd be inclined to suspect an "evil" 9v adapter first.  Once zapped it may be nothing but a heating element - potentially a mild one if a weak-current source like a 9v "transistor" battery is used.

Comment: On the assumption that is now worthless, could you put your volt meter (set to Volts, DC) black to GND, red to 5V pins (you may need hookup wire), plug it in and read the voltage; then do the same on 3.3V, and VIN, and post the results here.